# How to find out what computers are connected to an access point/router using Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, ip-address, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I would like to determine what computers are currently connected to my access point/router via the command line in Linux.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can also try:

`arp-scan [network/CIDR]`  eg: arp-scan 192.168.1.0/24

You may need to install [arp-scan](http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/) - most major distributions have it in their repos.

Answer (score 2):

`nmap -A -T4 'ip of your network'`

Comment: well just to make sure I did `ifconfig` to ifconfigfind my network ip and it returned **inet addr** as 192.168.1.101 so I then did `nmap -A -T4 192.168.1.101` and got this back Starting Nmap 5.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-02-12 16:48 CET
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -PN
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 2.09 seconds

Answer (score 2):

I use `arp -an`

```
mybox $ arp -an
? (172.16.17.135) à f0:1f:af:36:93:fa [ether] sur wlan1
? (172.16.17.143) à f8:16:54:95:ac:b2 [ether] sur wlan1
? (172.16.17.65) à 8c:70:5a:a4:74:a8 [ether] sur wlan1
? (172.16.17.1) à 00:1C:d4:01:06:0c [ether] sur wlan1
```

If you feel adventurous, you can use `arp -a` which will try to resolv IP.

This will show you only local host with active connection.

Edit:

`arp`  is somehow deprecated, now you sould use `ip n` (n as neighbour).

Comment: IMHO, the `-a` non-tabular output format is less lucid than without `-a`..

Answer (score 0):

Depending on Linux version and also on network configuration you need to supply network information for `arp-scan` so it knows what to scan as you may have (and usually you do) multiple interfaces.

I'd recommend this command options

```
sudo arp-scan --localnet --interface=en1
```

First of all, you may need `sudo` because `arp-scan` uses some services that require root privileges.

`--localnet` frees you from having to know your IP and it will scan 256 addresses like `192.168.1.0/24`but will handle address for you automagically.

`--interface=en1` is the interface it will use in case default `en0` is not your active link. To check which interface is active along with other useful information use

```
ifconfig
```

If you are using Mac OS X, you will need to install package. To do so, visit [Rudix repository](http://rudix.org/packages/arp-scan.html), download and install package (you will need administrative privileges and password) and then use like I suggested.