# What devices are connected to a given Access Point?

Tags: wireless-router, wireless-access-point, mac-address

How can I list what devices are connected to a given Access  Point? 
I have a central router for DHCP and gateway, and an AP that does not do these. So, most diagnostics  do not recognize the difference.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/841285/i)  is about how to tell which AP a device is connected to *from the device*. Some of my devices are embedded, so I cannot query BSSID *from* these devices.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/244296/) is related but does not show how to differentiate which specific router/API  (BSSID)  devices are connected to.

Comment: Without querying the AP directly it's pretty difficult unless your equipment has some proprietary management that allows a central service to accumulate connected devices, I'll guess. A way of separating might be to use VLANs with different subnets depending on whether a device is connected to the AP or elsewhere... You'll then be able to use the router and look at what devices have been leased IPs in your AP subnet vs those with IPs connected to the router...?

Comment: "Without querying the API directly" -- OK , how do I do that? I have access to the DLink admin interface of the AP, but see nothing relevant there.

Comment: Is there any page that shows connected devices? What's the make and model of the AP?

Comment: There is a page for connected devices, but apparently this is for DHCP or ARP, which does not distinguish per-AP